# ES6 class setter as a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, setter

I'm trying to submit the setter function of a class as a parameter.

Let's asume there is:

```
class A { 
    set foo(foo) {
        this._foo = foo
    } 
}
```

However, if I'm calling the `function f(setter) { setter(); }` like this `f(obj.foo)`, of course the value of `obj.foo` will be submitted calling the getter.

I was thinking about using an arrow function `(foo) => obj.foo = foo` and it works. But there must be a shorter way, something like `f(obj.setFoo)` to get the setter function.

Ideas are welcome.

Comment: What about `function f(obj, setter, value){ obj[setter] = value; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But there must be a shorter way, something like f(obj.setFoo) to get the setter function.

Nope.  There's a longer way,

```
var setFoo = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'foo').set;
setFoo.call(obj, 'bar');
```

Accessor functions are stored in the [internal property attributes](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-set-p-v-receiver) and are not accessible without using reflection.  Stick with your arrow function solution or define getter/setter functions (instead of an accessor property) on the class.

Answer (score 1):

You can always define a getter which returns the setter:

```js
class A {
  get foo() {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(A.prototype, 'foo').set;
  }
  set foo(foo) {
    this._foo = foo;
  }
}
var obj = new A();
(function(setter) {
  setter.call(obj, 123);
  console.log(obj._foo); // 123
})(obj.foo);
```